# Wordpress Confirm New Password

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I'd like to modify the password reset screen (wp-login.php?action=rp). Currently, the password reset screen generates a new password for the user and I want to add a "confirm password" field that is required.

I think I've found the relevant code in the wp-login.php file and it looks like there is a confirm password option but I don't know how to get it to appear.

```
<form name="resetpassform" id="resetpassform" action="<?php echo esc_url( network_site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=resetpass', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_login ); ?>" autocomplete="off" />

<div class="user-pass1-wrap">
    <p>
        <label for="pass1"><?php _e( 'New password' ) ?></label>
    </p>

    <div class="wp-pwd">
        <span class="password-input-wrapper">
            <input type="password" data-reveal="1" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_generate_password( 16 ) ); ?>" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="input" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
        </span>
        <div id="pass-strength-result" class="hide-if-no-js" aria-live="polite"><?php _e( 'Strength indicator' ); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>

<p class="user-pass2-wrap">
    <label for="pass2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password' ) ?></label><br />
    <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" class="input" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" />
</p>

<p class="description indicator-hint"><?php echo wp_get_password_hint(); ?></p>
<br class="clear" />

<?php
/**
 * Fires following the 'Strength indicator' meter in the user password reset form.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param WP_User $user User object of the user whose password is being reset.
 */
do_action( 'resetpass_form', $user );
?>
<input type="hidden" name="rp_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_key ); ?>" />
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Reset Password'); ?>" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it for the WP registration itself or are you using Woocommerce?

Comment: What have you tried, and why hasn't it worked?

Comment: @FusionDesign this is for the WP registration. The original code.

Comment: @Adam I only just started. I think I found where the code is but that's all. It looks like "user-pass2-wrap"class is disabled and I want to enable it.